# Train and Score Data set (Dimension not match)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I had a situation that the dimension of categorical variables in the training and scoring data set are not matched. For example, in the training data, the variable region had 3 categories: "East", "South", and "West" while the scoring data had 4 categories: "East", "South", "West", and "North". Since I had saved the model object using Python, I cannot score the data due to mismatch dimension. Any suggestions to take care of the additional categorical values in the scoring data set.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are splitting the data set into train and score data then first transform the categorical data and then split the data set to avoid this problem.